# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS upgrade failed from 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade

Hi I just tried to upgrade to 16.04 , which after installing some packages stopped working,  so I restarted the machine, now I can only see a black screen which shows the following msg .

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Trina- PC tty1
Trina- PC login :

My machine wad a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, please help me fix the failure.

Update:   Ijust logged in and sudo apt-get upgrade again, it seems it started the upgrade where it left from, I will wait to see what happens, I will come back if I see any error and v interruption again

Comment: That looks like a treminal login prompt to me. Can you login with your username and password?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried my username and password several times, it just returns me "login incorrect"

Comment: Do you have live media you can boot from? (optical or USB Flash?)

Comment: I just logged in and sudo apt-get upgrade again, it seems it started the upgrade where it left from, I will wait to see what happens, I will come back if I see any error and v interruption again

Comment: I once had a similar problem, upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10. I had a power failure and Ubuntu was a mess. All I could see when I rebooted was a black screen. I did a fresh install from the `.iso`.